# Finding a value and then copying a column in which it occurs

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a macro which will find a value "Spot price" in a header of a table2 and then take the whole column where that value is to copy and paste it (as values and not formulas). I need to do it because in that column I have a reference to external workbook and I need to share this worksheet without sharing the other workbook. This is what I wrote

```
Sub row()
Dim firstrow As Range
Dim ColumnToPaste As Range
Dim copy As Range

Set firstrow = Worksheets("Raw Data").ListObjects("Table2").HeaderRowRange
Set ColumnToPaste = firstrow.Find("Spot price", , xlValues, xlWhole).Columns(1)

With Worksheets("Raw Data").Range(ColumnToPaste)
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End With

End Sub
```

The error occurs on this line (Application-defined or object-defined error):

```
With Worksheets("Raw Data").Range(ColumnToPaste)
```

I think I'm using wrong range argument but not sure how to write it properly.

Comment: You have already provided parent worksheet and listobject reference for ColumnToPaste. Just use `With ColumnToPaste`.

Comment: Then I get `PasteSpecial method of Range class failed`

Comment: that makes sense since you haven't copied anything.

Comment: Just a note: Don't use `copy` as variable name (`Dim copy As Range`) this is already a method name used by Excel. Before you can paste something you need to copy. I suggest to add a `.Copy` line right before the `.PasteSpecial` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following, instead of copying the full column, specify the range:

```
Sub row2()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Raw Data")
'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
Dim firstrow As Range
Dim ColumnToPaste As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

Set firstrow = ws.ListObjects("Table2").HeaderRowRange
Set ColumnToPaste = firstrow.Find("Spot price", , xlValues, xlWhole).Columns
col = ColumnToPaste.Column
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column A
With ws
    .Range(.Cells(1, col), .Cells(LastRow, col)).Copy
    .Range(.Cells(1, col), .Cells(LastRow, col)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, this would work too. As my range is a table, End(xlUp) doesn't work for copying and pasting values. Instead I used a specific number of rows (as the table always has the same amount of rows in my case). BTW. It's second time you are helping me. Thanks :)

Comment: @Seidhe no problem, glad to be of assistance, we might cross paths in future again... :)